# mongoReactiveTemplate aggregation Query

Tags: spring-mvc

I am new to Reactive.My requirement is to find All records(streaming Data)from Mongo Database.but I need apply aggregation over findAll() method of reactivemongorepository.
mycode is here..

```
reactiveRepository.findAll().limitRate(2).delayElements(Duration.ofSeconds(2)).log()
```

please help